# another regex email post (in php)

Tags: php, regex

Im handling various email addresses that come in the following forms

```
John Doe <5555555555@mail.com>
5555555555@mail.com
```

How could i use regex, to find the @ symbol, and then return the integer's behind it (until it doesnt find anymore, or runs into a non number, < or space for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^\D*(\d*)@/
```

Will match any number of non-digits, any number of digits, followed by an @.

The capturing group will contain the digits.

Comment: could you provide an example of this usage in php?

Comment: Chris Gutierrez's answer has an example of the syntax for regex matching in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for this regex:

```
(\d*)@
```

And then look at the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like...

```
preg_match("#^[\D]+\<([\d]+)#", "John Doe <5555555555@mail.com>", $matches);
```

Comment: This won't match the second example posted.